# Access from a different classes to the RichTextBox of MainForm.cs (Windows Forms Application)

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

For example, in same class I'm using "this" word. But how can I access to THIS RichTextBox from another class.

```
private void deleteSymbol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string text = this.dataTextBox.Text;
      this.dataTextBox.Text = text.Remove(0, 1);
}
```

Examples below are not working.

```
MainForm mf = new MainForm();
mf.dataTextBox.Text = text.Remove(0, 1);
```

or

```
MainForm mf; 
mf.dataTextBox.Text = text.Remove(0, 1);
```

doesn't works.

Comment: It doesn't work because the dataTextBox variable is not public. I would suggest reading up on OOP principles and the basics of C# before your proceed.

Comment: I understand that, but I thought possible ways are exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

In your main form;

```
public  MainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  main = this;
}

internal static MainForm main;
internal string Status
{
    get { return dataTextBox.Text.ToString(); }
    set { dataTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

From your calling class,

```
MainForm.main.Status = "Your message";
```

:)

Comment: I will try.... but this way will not help with some functions... for example... what if I need to use... this.dataTextBox.Lines array? Then I have to create in MainForm.cs a method which will convert it back and force?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change the Modifiers property of your richtextbox control to public or some other accessible options to allow other classes identify your control. then your codes would work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing your richtextbox to public, I would suggest implementing public properties on your mainform. Call these specific properties to do some work for you on the mainform's richtextbox...

Public property in your mainform:

```
Private newRTBtext As String
Public Property RTBtext() As String
    Get
        Return RichTextBox1.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        newRTBtext = value
        RichTextBox1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Call this property on mainform to set or get text in your richtextbox... this is an example property, create the properties and methods you need.